Unable to load preload script: Resources/app.asar/src/renderer.js
My preload is named renderer.js
I have an electron app that I compiled using Electron Builder, my app features numerous HTML pages, most of them get redirected from button clicks.
When I click a button to navigate to another html page, the same preload error is logged there and the app turns white. After closing devtools in that same state, it just becomes transparent, the app is still open but the HTML & CSS does not seem to be loading.
How do I configure the package.json so that the preload gets detected?

// This is my main file, main.js

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1700,
        height: 810,
        minWidth: 1700,
        minHeight: 810,
        resizable: false,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.resolve(app.getAppPath(), 'renderer.js'),
            contextIsolation: true,
            enableRemoteModule: false,
            nodeIntegration: false,
            webSecurity: false
        },
        transparent: true,
        frame: false,
        backgroundColor: '#00000000',
    });
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'Pages', 'index.html'));

    mainWindow.on('will-resize', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}

//preload.js

const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer, shell } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    send: (channel, data) => ipcRenderer.send(channel, data),
    on: (channel, func) => ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args)),
    receive: (channel, func) => {
        ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
    },
});

// package.json

  "build": {
  "appId": "com.example.test",
  "productName": "test",
  "files": [
    "dist/**/*",
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "main.js",
    "configs.json",
    "package.json",
    "Managers/**/*",
    "Images/**/*",
    "Pages/**/*",
    "Tasks/**/*",
    "renderer.js"
  ],
  "directories": {
    "output": "build"
  }
}


If you read the docs about preload, you will see that it's not like this that you set the path to preload.
